# Is there any way to validate NTP asymmetric keys

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I am working on implementing NTP authentication by asymmetric key (autokey).
I just want a way to validate those keys. Is there any utility in `ntp-keygen` to validate them?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is [here in the ntp docs](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringAutokey#Section_6.7.4.):

> Use `ntpq -c "rv 0 cert"` to view the Autokey certificates held by ntpd.
>   Use ntpq -c as to the check the authentication status of NTP associations. Authenticated associations display ok in the auth column:

```
ind assID status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 26132  f694   yes   yes   ok   sys.peer   reachable  9
```

> For detailed information about an authenticated association use the assID from ntpq -cas in the following command: `ntpq -c"rv assID flags"`

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I just wanted to validate my ntp keys if they are tempered or not and if it got modified during copying from server. Except for generating hash , is there any other solution from ntp-keygen or any other tool?